# Adding complicated selections to CriteriaBuilder in EclipseLink?

Tags: java, eclipselink

i want add some more complicated selections as below on date coloumn

```
select TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), to_char(TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'FMDAY') day,
       (case when to_char(trunc(TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'mm'), 'FMDAY') = 'SUNDAY' then to_number(to_char(TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'W'))
             else ceil((to_char(TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'dd') + 1 - to_char(next_day(trunc(TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'mm'), 'SUNDAY'), 'dd'))/7)
        end)+1 week_no
from dual
```

here breakupFields is list of string which leads to date column

```
final QueryBuilder distinctDateTimeFilter = new QueryBuilder() {
final List<String> breakupFields = new ArrayList<String>(fields.length);
        for (final String f : fields) 
            if (!Strings.isEmpty(f)) {
                breakupFields.add(f);
            }
        }
         final QueryBuilder distinctDateTimeFilter = new QueryBuilder() {
            @Override
        public CriteriaQuery buildQuery(CriteriaBuilder cb, CriteriaQuery query, Predicate p, List orders, Root rt) {

            Expression selection = null;

            selection = cb.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, cb.sum(CriteriaQueryUtils.getPath(rt, breakupFields), cb.literal(miliSecToAdd)),
                            cb.literal("W-MM-YYYY"));

         return query.select(selection).distinct(true).where(p).orderBy(orders);
         }
         }

    final List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<Object>(ds.executeQuery(classObject, Object.class, distinctDateTimeFilter, ef, session,

            SuperUserSecurityContext.class));
```

Can any one suggest how to add

```
(case when to_char(trunc(TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'mm'), 'FMDAY') = 'SUNDAY' then to_number(to_char(TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'W'))
             else ceil((to_char(TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'dd') + 1 - to_char(next_day(trunc(TO_DATE ('04-JAN-2015','DD-MM-YYYY'), 'mm'), 'SUNDAY'), 'dd'))/7)
        end)+1 to criteria builder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a column in your Entity marked as

```
@Formula(value="the expression")
```

See more [here](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation) and use the column in the queries.

Or you can define native SQL query with the desired entity class mapped and use fuly native SQL.

Comment: we cannot use @Formula(value="the expression") because there are many date columns in a one entity class

Comment: and besides he's using EclipseLink, so you need to use JPA and some Formula annotation of one implementation is of no use then